Azure MySQL and AWS RDS insert performance difference
We had to move our infra from AWS to Azure (reasons irrelevant) and I've set up a same spec DB instance on Azure, even a tier larger (2c/8g on AWS and 2c/16g on Azure, both memory optimized). What I've noticed is that the performance on large tables are much worse and having way more deadlocks on Azure than on AWS. Total DB size is ~12G, so the 16g memory should be enough on Azure, but inserting data on a table with ~4m record sometimes take like 15 seconds or even more, just a single insert. And a few select from larger tables much slower than on RDS. There was even an instance of an update query which just updated a timestamp based on a PK which took like 15 seconds and the table wasn't even that large. The QPS on this was around 2-3 so not that big of a traffic. The slow inserts are not "constant" but periodic.
I'm having a hunch of this being an issue with IOPS. On RDS the provision  IOPS  is 3k, but on Azure, I've been runinng with 1k. That's the only difference that I could find.
I've compared the parameter groups on both instances and haven't found any outstanding differences. I'm quite lost on how to even start to fix this.

every connection open its own table cache so that 4 or more make the memory go fast down. you can tweak it but if you n ot have permission to change the my.cnf/ini you are stuck wuith the configuration you have

I get that, it's just that it's a tad weird that an almost same hardware configuration has so much different in behaviour. Nothing jumps out neither on the used memory chart or on the cpu load, or any other metric. There are a few row lock wait time and 2-3 deadlock during a day, but that can be solved from app side. Also I dont think the deadlocks matter in this case as they don't correlate when a slow query happens.

you can show varable and see if there is any difference between both configurations

For more analysis: https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis -- provide both the SHOWs and the slowlog.

Thanks Rick, I've uploaded the variables here, the slowlog is filling up at this moment:
Azure variables
https://justpaste.it/dp8e2
AWS variables
https://justpaste.it/ddorx
